# Foreach on getRepository Symfony 3

Tags: symfony

On my controler I get some results from database

```
$commandes = $em->getRepository('SWPlatformBundle:Vente')->getCommandesAFacturer($client[0]->getId());
```

with this SQL

```
public function getCommandesAFacturer($id) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
      ->select("c.id, c.montantTTC, c.horodatageCreation, SUM(v.prixTotalVente) AS sansFrais")
      ->leftJoin('v.commande', 'c')

  ->where('c.facture IS NULL')
  ->andwhere('c.commercant = :commercantId')
  ->setParameter('commercantId', $id)
  ->groupBy('c.id');

return $qb
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
}
```

And I would like to sum the sansFrais value of my request but I don't reach the sansFrais Value.

I've tried like this, but it doesn't work :

```
foreach($commandes as $commande){
    $montantHTCollecte += $commande['sansFrais'];
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What do you mean by "don't reach"? What happens instead?

Comment: try with `getScalarResult()` instead of `getResult()`. And the above comment is very valid, it would be helpful to know what "don't reach" and "doesn't work" mean in practice.

Comment: getScalarResult only returns one value such as count(*).  Might want to just dump out a $commande array and see what is in there.

Comment: Ok sorry, I will try to be clearer. My SQL request returns a list of commands and I want to calculate the sum of "sansFrais" field for all the list. When I try the foreach loop I have this error : Warning: A non-numeric value encountered.

Comment: Probable just need to cast $commande['sansFrais'] to an integer or float.  Unless the warning is coming from someplace completely different.

Comment: on dev you usually have `dd` at your disposal for print-debugging. in your foreach, try `dd($commande)` to see what is actually contained in `$commandes`. however, it is very likely, that `getResult` really must be replaced with `getScalarResult`, as ejuhjav mentioned.

Comment: Thanks to everyone... I found the solution :     foreach($commandes as $commande){$montantHTCollecte = (float)$montantHTCollecte + $commande['sansFrais'];
     }